# add sub Route in the beginning of route path (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I have angular project and I need when user type the URL like [www.mysite.com/hisName](http://www.mysite.com/hisName) , Take this name and add it to all routing pages in my project  and the final result will be like [www.mysite.com/hisName/home](http://www.mysite.com/hisName/home)

this is my routing code

```
    import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
    import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

    const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "home", component: HomeComponent },
     path: "supliers",
     loadChildren: () =>
       import("./supliers-container/supliers-container.module").then(
     (mod) => mod.SupliersContainerModule
     ),
  }


 @NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
   exports: [RouterModule],
  })
   export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for something like a wildcard option? It does have to be defined as the last element.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "home", component: HomeComponent },
    { path: "supliers",
     loadChildren: () =>
       import("./supliers-container/supliers-container.module").then(
          (mod) => mod.SupliersContainerModule
        ),
     },

     { path "**", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full" } // here
]
```

Note: if you add the wildcard, I don't think you need the first path option.